# AngularJs jquery plugin map chart data update

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to update data value of a rendered map chart. I use a jquery plugin, jVectorMap.

The problem is that when I try to update the dataset, a new chart is appended to the the dom, just after the old one.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/eTyLpb3dAJf3AAmjrqDX?p=preview

```
app.directive('map', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       scope.$watch("mapdata" , function(n,o){
            $(element).width('auto')
            $(element).height(400)
            $(element).vectorMap({
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                regionStyle: { 
                  initial: {
                    fill: '#cccccc'
                  }
                },
                series: {
                    regions: [{ 
                        values: scope.mapdata,
                        scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
                        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                    }]
                },
            });              
        });              
    }
};
});
```

Another approach could be this:

```
app.directive('map', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var chart = null;

      var data = scope.datamap;
       scope.$watch("data" , function(n,o){ 
         if(!chart){
            $(element).width('auto')
            $(element).height(400)
            chart = $(element).vectorMap({})
         }else{
            chart.vectorMap('set', 'colors', {us: '#000000'});
            console.log(chart)
         }
      });              
    }
};
});
```

Plunkr:     http://plnkr.co/edit/ib3Rgz?p=preview

With this approach I can change the background color but not the state colors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jVectorMap is appending the new map to the element.

You can:

1. Clear the element before updating with `element.empty();` (plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/i8q39s?p=preview)
2. Grab the mapObject of the vector map:

   ```
   var mapobject = element.vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
   ```

   and update it from the watch with the scope data. This way is probably more 'angular'.

Comment: I'm not sure where I should set var mapobject...I've updated the plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/ib3Rgz?p=preview), trying a different approach based on this article http://eric-schaefer.com/blog/2013/07/26/rendering-flot-charts-through-angular-js/

Comment: @jojo could you publish a Plunkr with your option 2?